Finding a condition to bound $f$ satisfying an integral inequality
I was concerning the following problem:

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)\ge 0$, $f(0)\ne 0$. Let $g$ be an integrable function on $[0,\infty)$ such that $$\int_0^\infty e^{2x}g(x)\mathrm{d}x<\infty.$$ Let $1/2<p<1$, if $$f(x)\le f(0)+\int_0^x(x-y)^{p-1}f(y)g(y)\mathrm{d}y,$$ show that $f$ is bounded.

I managed to work this out via Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, where the core observation is that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x{\left( x-y \right) ^{p-1}f\left( y \right) g\left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y}&=\int_0^x{\left( x-y \right) ^{p-1}e^ye^{-y}f\left( y \right) g\left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y}
\\
&\le \left( \int_0^x{\left( x-y \right) ^{2p-2}e^{-2y}\mathrm{d}y} \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_0^x{e^{2y}f^2\left( y \right) g^2\left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y} \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}},
\end{aligned}
$$
where the integral in the first bracket is bounded via a direct computation, and then apply Gronwall's inequality to finish the proof.
However, what I really want to ask is whether this is an "if and only if" condition, i.e. can we weaken the condition described about $g$ to obtain the same result? If we can, then what is it? If we cannot, then how can we prove the converse? I managed to find a counter-example if $\int_0^\infty g(x)\mathrm{d}x<\infty$, however I wonder if there are some improvement.
Any advice is appreciated.
